# How to prevent WhatsApp from leaving a conversation when I scrolling it up?

Tags: whatsapp

I have got a Windows Phone [Lumia 620] with WhatsApp [version 2.11.688].
Whenever I click on a conversation [or I am in the middle of a conversation] and want to check it over by scrolling it up to check some messages that I want to examine again, WhatsApp after some time [about 20 seconds or thereabouts] WhatsApp all of a sudden makes me go away from the conversation and it redirects me to the main screen [the Start menu with all the apps].
I tried to archive and/or save the chat and send it by e-mail so that I would manage to check over the conversation quietly, but it is not what I wanted to do, because actually I would like to find again something I recorded through the rec button near the textbox [the space wherein to type] and in the e-mail of course I cannot hear it.

So, how to prevent WhatsApp from forcing me to leave the conversation?
Only when I do such a thing, the conversation disappears.

Thank you.

Comment: Sounds to me like the app is crashing. Does this happen with every conversation?

Comment: Yes, it happens with every WhatsApp conversation. What should I do? Download once again WhatsApp from the App Store?

Comment: Might be worth a shot - however I'm not sure how exactly WhatsApp handles backups and restoration of those.

Comment: May be an update issue. Back the chat up and try re-installing it.

Comment: I tried the same but couldn't reproduce the problem.